# Is it possible to detect swipe to new fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to execute some code in my viewpage fragments when the user swipes to a new fragment. Something to act like a button onClickListener. I have a EditText in one of my fragments and need to store this to file when the user swipes to the next fragment.

Should I do this in the ViewPager class? Or the fragment class? It would be easiest if its possible to do it from the fragment itself. A button would make it easy, but I want it to do it on swipe.

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to [call `setOnPageChangeListener()` on your `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29), supplying an `OnPageChangeListener` implementation, to be notified about page changes.